# Search for value in column Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to match a value in a cell, with an entire column. In other words, if col1 contains the current record in col2, it should be a match. **Even though it is not in the same row.** The results should be as follows:

```
Col1       Col2       Result
-------    -------    -------
A          B          match
B          F          not match
C          C          match
D          A          match
```

I have looked into VLOOKUP and LOOKUP but it does not seem to be able to provide me with what I need

Here is what I have tried so far:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P:P,C:C,15,FALSE), "NO MATCH")

in col 17 which resulted to:

```
col15  col16 col17
A      D     NO MATCH
B      B     NO MATCH
C      A     NO MATCH
D      F     NO MATCH
```

Comment: Why is it not working? Can you include the formula you've tried?

Comment: Is `C:C` column the lookup column? If so, the `P:P` reference should point to every cell you want to compare, as `P1`, `P2` and so on

Answer (score 1):

This may also help you. Try following formula.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$5,0)>0,"Match"),"Not Match")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P:P,C:C,15,FALSE), "NO MATCH")`

didn't work because your *Vlookup* results to an error.
Main reason is you put `15` in *column_index* but you actually don't have 15th column since you only select 1 column which is `C:C` for *table_array*.

Another is you *lookup_value* should be a single cell so instead of `P:P`, it should be `P1` for example.

To make it work, you will need to change it to:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P1,C:C,1,FALSE), "NO MATCH")`

It will result to the value found or "NO MATCH" for non existing value.
To get your desired result, this formula should work.

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(P1,C:C,1,FALSE)),"not match","match")`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with:

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(A:A;MATCH(B1;A:A;0);1));"NOT MATCH";"MATCH")
```

Where:

- `A:A`: the  range where you want to search for values; in your example, the `Col1`; notice that range appears twice in the formula
- `B1`: the value you're looking for; in your example, every values from `Col2`

Try to remove the `IF` and `ISNA` functions to see how the `INDEX` behaves when it doesn't find a match.

This approach is superior to the `VLOOKUP` alternative, as it doesn't requires the lookup column to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you are using match formula? Use this formula....

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,$A$2:$A$5,0)),"Match","Not match")
```

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If value in B is found anywhere in Column A, then put value in B

```
=IF((IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1; $A$1:$A$9999; 1; 0)=B1);B1;""))=0;"";(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1; $A$1:$A$9999; 1; 0)=B1);"";B1)))
```

---

If value in B is not found anywhere in Column A, then put value in B

```
=IF((IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1; $A$1:$A$9999; 1; 0)=B1);B1;""))=0;"";(IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1; $A$1:$A$9999; 1; 0)=B1);B1;"")))
```

[image: 1]